# nginx : Http Response code for redirected request's response

Tags: nginx, http-response-codes

We use nginx as reverse proxy. We would like nginx to follow redirects from proxy and use the Location header on 302. I could get this working using intercepting errors(proxy_intercept_errors on) and following the redirects using the Location header when 302 is received from upstream server. However, the http response code for this response is still 302. I tried both the browser and curl. Is this an expected behavior?
Posted the relevant config. Hope this helps.

```
   server   {  
      location /      {  
         proxy_intercept_errors on; 
                error_page 302 @handle_redirects;
      }      location @handle_redirects      {  
         set $redirect_upstream_http_location $upstream_http_location; 
            proxy_pass $redirect_upstream_http_location;
      }
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: Post your nginx config

Answer (score 0):

Change your config to below

```
   server   {  
      location /      {  
         proxy_intercept_errors on; 
                error_page 302 301 307 = @handle_redirects;
      }
      location @handle_redirects      {  
         set $redirect_upstream_http_location $upstream_http_location; 
            proxy_pass $redirect_upstream_http_location;
      }
   }
```

From nginx documentation

> Furthermore, it is possible to change the response code to another using the “=response” syntax, for example:
>
> error_page 404 =200 /empty.gif;
>   If an error response is processed by a proxied server or a FastCGI/uwsgi/SCGI server, and the server may return different response codes (e.g., 200, 302, 401 or 404), it is possible to respond with the code it returns:
>
> error_page 404 = /404.php;

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think i was missing the =. Let me try that.